# Image slider not loading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the html for my website. I would like to add this `image slider:`. I have one problem, for some reason all I get is 4 bullet point and a error `img` picture next to it. Could you look at my html and see what you could do to help.

-Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/lasquish/hL7vLcd5/

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="slider">
        <li><img src="/images/Day1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="/images/Day1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="/images/Day1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="/images/Day1.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the Script:

```
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: did you call bxslider.js

Comment: if the image isn't showing up, check the paths

Comment: You would have to call the `boxslider.js` **after** calling JQuery...wouldn't you? Also you seem to be calling JQuery twice...and different versions

Comment: You're also loading two versions of jquery. remove `1.11.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have wrapped slide content with .slider class you need to do following changes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').bxSlider();
});
```

Call bxslider.min.js after jQuery library
Also you have call 2 different version of jQuery library. this will make conflict.

Comment: Explain why the user needs to select `.slider` instead, in your answer

Comment: And fix the indentation :)

Comment: @Brian maybe because the users ul element has the class of "slider"

Comment: It didnt seem to work. Here is a js fiddle of my changes. I have checked the picture file path and they seemed to be correct. Could you look at this and tell me what i did wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/lasquish/8umetf7h/

Comment: @r3wt, I was aware of the reason, was encouraging a thorough answer.

Comment: @Brian it was undoubtedly week, but the OP needs to learn to think logically anyway.

Comment: @alex: seems you have call js library's inside the html area. jsfiddle doesnt allow it. you have to select js liberarys from left side panel. and javascript should b write in script area

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add below css to remove bullet

   ul
   {
       list-style-type: none;
   }
2. Need to use correct image path or you can use full image "http://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png"...

As you have not shared all required file here ..so we unable to test at our end. Please share js library file which you have include here if problem no solve.